# Create multiple columns using list

Tags: r

I've got a list of dataframe `my_OHLCV_data` and I'm having trouble creating a new column with a list with the correspondent names.

This is what I got:

```
 print(my_OHLCV_data)
    [[1]]
               Open High Low Close   Volume Adjusted
    2019-03-11 8.61  8.8 5.9  8.54 12245200     8.54

    [[2]]
               Open High  Low Close   Volume Adjusted
    2019-03-08 1.75  2.9 1.43  1.54 21725300     1.54

    [[3]]
               Open High  Low Close   Volume Adjusted
    2019-02-22 2.78 4.54 2.72   3.3 68893400      3.3

    print(symbols_names)
    [1] "TTNP" "AVCO" "CCCL"
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
  print(my_OHLCV_data)
    [[1]]
               Open High Low Close   Volume Adjusted  Symbol
    2019-03-11 8.61  8.8 5.9  8.54 12245200     8.54    TTNP

    [[2]]
               Open High  Low Close   Volume Adjusted  Symbol
    2019-03-08 1.75  2.9 1.43  1.54 21725300     1.54    AVCO

    [[3]]
               Open High  Low Close   Volume Adjusted  Symbol
    2019-02-22 2.78 4.54 2.72   3.3 68893400      3.3    CCCL
```

This is what I came up with and it wasn't even close:

```
my_OHLCV_data$name <- symbols_names
print(my_OHLCV_data)
          [[1]]
                     Open High Low Close   Volume Adjusted
          2019-03-11 8.61  8.8 5.9  8.54 12245200     8.54

          [[2]]
                     Open High  Low Close   Volume Adjusted
          2019-03-08 1.75  2.9 1.43  1.54 21725300     1.54

          [[3]]
                     Open High  Low Close   Volume Adjusted
          2019-02-22 2.78 4.54 2.72   3.3 68893400      3.3

          $name 
          [1] "TTNP" "AVCO" "CCCL"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, `Map` should do it

```
Map(cbind, my_OHLCV_data, Symbol = symbols_names)
```

---

Or using `purrr::map2`

```
purrr::map2(my_OHLCV_data, symbols_names,~cbind(.x, Symbol = .y))
```